# How to loop through some items in an array in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My question is regarding how to iterate partially through an array in React JSX. Instead of calling .map and iterating through all the items in profile.categories, I only want to display the first five items in the array. I currently have the following code:

```
<div className="categories">
   {profile.categories.map(category => (
       <div
         className="profile-categories"
         style={{ float: "left" }}
       >
         {category}
       </div>
     ))}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use slice directly on profile.categories, like so:

```
<div className="categories">
{profile.categories.slice(0, 5).map(category => (
   <div
     className="profile-categories"
     style={{ float: "left" }}
   >
     {category}
   </div>
 ))}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with map:

```
profile.categories.slice(0, 5).map(...)
```

Also you can add method for getting some count of categories in component:

```
getFirst(count) {
  return profile.categories.slice(0, count);
}

// and then in render:
this.getFirst(5).map(...)
```